# Finding a state/county programmatically, given the boundaries of each area and a latitude/longitude

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, latitude-longitude, reverse-geocoding

Assume that you have the boundaries of states/counties of any country in a text file as follows:

```
State \t State Name \t Lat/Long of entire State Boundary(comma separated).
```

I want to to store this information in a data structure** and then given a lat-long, retrieve the state.

I don't want to use APIs and don't want to do the brute force approach (that is, build a polygon for each state and then do a [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm until a hit)

With my limited knowledge, I think KD-Trees or R-Trees is the way to do? Although both of the seem like good choice, I am not sure which one to use. It would be very helpful if you can provide a detailed explanation - from creating the Data Structure to performing the search.

I am more interested in the counties than states because of their finer granularity. May be it is worth stopping the tree building at a larger granularity and then do a point in polygon approach for all the counties in that granularity (Minimum bounding region). Conceptually this seems doable, but I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I have search SO and found related questions and hence got ideas about KD-Trees and R-Trees but not the implementation details.

Comment: have a look at MySQL spatial database function [**MBRContains()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html)

Comment: @davidstrachan Just doing that, I guess that it would be same as the brute force approach.

Comment: Look at any GeoSpatial library (in the language of your choice) and it will have a spatially indexed point in polygon which will be faster and better than anything you can write your self

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already chosen a Geospatial friendly database, pick [Postgis](https://postgis.net/). [Mysql 5.7](https://web.archive.org/web/20190107035843/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) will also do the trick but Postgis is more mature and feature rich.[2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Download the [world borders shapefile.](https://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php)

Import the shapefile into [postgis](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage) or into [mysql](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

Make use of the `ST_Within` function available in both mysql and postgis to determine if a given point is inside any country and to retrieve the name or other information for that country.

Note that the `ST_within` query is fast, and you don't need to do a lot hard on your own. This is a one liner.

Setting up the database and importing the database maybe hard work, but you will have to do that anyway even if you come up with a home made solution.